# Is it wrong to create a different store just for testing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, jestjs

I would like to create integration tests of sagas + reducers + actions, but all the documentation about testing redux I can see uses the `redux-mock-store` function.

```
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
```

Can someone offer an explanation on why is this, and why not just using a complete store?

Thanks

Comment: Because those examples are for unit tests. You probably should go for a full store implementation for integration testing.

Comment: True, thanks @R.HalukÖngör

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not *wrong* to create a complete redux store for testing if this object is a replica of a Redux store created solely for the purpose of testing. What would be wrong is if the mock store you created wasn't an accurate replica of the redux store.

**The main advantage of redux-mock-store is that it makes it easier to test asynchronous Redux actions and middleware.**

As Dan Abramov says on the subject of testing async redux actions that call an api -

> For async action creators using Redux Thunk or other middleware, it’s
>   best to completely mock the Redux store for tests. You can still use
>   applyMiddleware() with a mock store, as shown below (you can find the
>   following code in redux-mock-store). You can also use nock to mock the
>   HTTP requests.

An extremely useful part of the libary's api the ability to get an array of the historical actions that have been dispatched.

> store.getActions() => actions: Array

This is especially useful for testing asynchronous actions which will dispatch multiple actions over a period of time.

An example taken from the docs:

```
// Test example with mocha and expect 
it('should dispatch action', () => {
  const initialState = {}
  const addTodo = { type: 'ADD_TODO' }

  const store = mockStore(initialState)
  store.dispatch(addTodo)

  const actions = store.getActions()

  expect(actions).toEqual([addTodo])
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, fits perfectly for my scenario. I thought it made sense but I wanted to have an external opinion.